# Can anyone explain me piece of code in c

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    int numChars = printf("Pls give me a floor to stand on\n");
    while (numChars>1)
    {
        printf("-");
        numChars--;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

1st Question is it possible to find the length of any kind of string by just using f.e. int numChars=printf("Pls...") and it will give me the exact number of elements of string?

2nd Question is considering the condition of while statement, why numChar>1 should be more than one, it means all previous numbers are less than one?

Comment: Use `strlen` to get the size of string.

Comment: I know about strlen, my question is the way the length of the string found in my example is alternative to strlen? Because, it complied and gave the right result, but I couldn't find any source that explaines how it is getting the number

Comment: Read the below [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41395720/2455888).

Comment: What do you mean with "all previous numbers are less than one"? `numChars` will be ~31 when you reach the `while` loop. In the loop it gets decremented until you reach 0.

Comment: Yeap, I got the notion. Thank you everyone.

Comment: This will not work `int numChars = printf("Some string with % in it");`  The first parameter given to `printf()` is a  string to be used as a _format_.  A `%` in that string causes _formatting_ of data to happen.  Using `printf()` to find a string's length is unwise.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` function will return the number of characters printed. So, if printing goes normally, it will return the number of characters in the string.

After that, the loop will print the `-` character for 1 less than the number of characters printed. This is to account for the `\n` character at the end.

So the final result will be the first line with a line of `------` below that.

Answer (score 0):

1) printf returns the number of characters printed on console. So here 
"Pls give me a floor to stand on" will return 31. And 31 will get stored in you variable numChars.
The while loop will keep printing '-' on console and decrements the count after each print. The loop will continue till the condition is true, i.e till numChar is greater then 1.

2) That is conditional check, initial value is 31 for numChar.